# String Comparison return value (Is is used in applications that sorts characters ?)

Tags: c++, string, compare

When we use `strcmp(str1, str2);` or `str1.compare(str2);` the return values are like -1, 0 and 1, for str1 < str2, str1 == str2 or str1 > str2 respectively.

The question is, is it defined like this for a specific reason? 
For instance, in binary tree sorting algorithm, we push smaller values to the left child and larger values to the right child. This strcmp or string::compare functions seem to be perfect for that. However, does anyone use string matching in order to sort a tree (integer index are easier to use) ?

So, what is the actual purpose of the three return values ( -1, 0, 1). Why cant it just return 1 for true, and  0 for false?

Thanks

Comment: The return value is not actually (-1, 0, 1). If you look at the [reference documents](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) it will just say a value less than zero, zero or a value greater than zero. For integers, you can just say `return num1 - num2;` ; for strings, it's similar.

Comment: @Bala R: Actually you can't compare integers like that (underflow/overflow).

Comment: @UncleBens: You can, since the function only works on ASCII text. And therefore, all input can be assumed to be on the range [0, 0x80).

Comment: @Nicol: ... and assuming **char** is a signed type?

Comment: @UncleBens: Even if it is signed, ASCII stops at 0x79, which is positive. It's not an ASCII string if it has values >= 0x80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of having three return values is exactly what it seems like: to answer all questions about string comparisons at once.

Everyone has different needs. Some people sometimes need a simple less-than test; `strncmp` provides this. Some people need equality testing; `strncmp` provides this. Some people really do need to know the full relationship between two strings; `strncmp` provides this.

What you absolutely don't want is someone writing this:

```
if(strless(lhs, rhs))
{
}
else if(strequal(lhs, rhs))
{
}
```

That's doing two potentially expensive comparison operations. `strless` also knows if they were equal, because it had to get to the end of both strings to return that it was not less.

Oh, and FYI: the return values isn't -1 or +1; it's greater than zero or less than zero. Or zero if they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful for certain cases where knowing all three cases is important. Use `operator<` for `string` when you just care about a boolean comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It could, but then you would need multiple functions for sorting and comparison. With strcmp() returning smaller, equal or bigger, you can use them easily for comparison and for sorting.

Remember that BSTs are not the only place where you would like to compare strings. You might want to sort a name list or similar. Also,  it is not uncommon to have a string as key in a tree too.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, there are real purposes for comparison of strings with < > == implications.  For example; fixed length numbers assigned to strings will resolve correctly; ie: "312235423" > "312235422".  On some occasions this is useful.

However the feature you're asking for, true/false for solutions still works with the given return values.

```
if (-1)
  {
     // resolves true
  }
else if (1)
  {
     // also resolves true
  }
 else if (0)
  {
    // resolves false
  }
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't right. You should be comparing that the values are greater than, less than, or equal to zero: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/