# why does return -1 sort the first value of an array before the second in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, comparator

```
   function compare (value1, value2) {
    if(value1 < value2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (value1 > value2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

var values = [0, 6, 8, 5];
values.sort(compare);
alert(values); // 0,5,6,8
```

I know that -1 means the first goes before the second and 1 means it goes after but what is the logic behind this? does this -1 0 and 1 apply to methods other than sort?

Comment: The "logic" is that that is how the `compare` function is defined to work with `sort`.

Comment: I suppose it is JavaScript. Please add the tag for it.

Comment: Ascending sort is the default order. In that order, values that come first have a lower value than those that come after. If you have two numbers `15` and `20`, for example, comparing them like `compare(15, 20)` would be like doing `15 - 20`, or `-5`. Since it's a negative number, that means the first number is less and comes first. The `-1, 0, 1` convention is so this same principle can apply to non-numerical types.

Comment: Related: [String Comparison return value (Is is used in applications that sorts characters ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7614852/218196) ... the comparator function has to return one of three states for indicating whether the value is larger, equal or smaller. A boolean only provides two values. There isn't a typical data type to represent three states. However, almost all programming languages have a number data type, and the three states can be expressed as a negative number, `0` or a positive number.

Comment: Note that this negative/zero/positive three-state concept was used in other languages that predate JS. Aside from being a simple way to represent three states it also gives a convenient shortcut for sorting numbers: your `compare()` function can just have a one-line `return a-b` instead of the `if/else if/else` structure.

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to think about it is if you subtract two numbers `a` from `b` and you get a negative number that must mean that `b` was larger, if you get a positive number then `a` was larger, and if you get `0` then they were both equal. `sort()` will sort based on which is smaller, larger, and equal.

Ex:

case of -1

```
a = 6 and b = 7
a - b = -1 // b is larger
```

case of 1

```
a = 6 and b = 5
a - b = 1 // a is larger
```

case of 0

```
a = 6 and b = 6 
a - b = 0 // both are equal
```

Comment: i guess what my question is, is why returning a -1 or 0 or 1 sort the numbers in the array in the first place. my question has to do with the return itself. like if i return "joe" it would return joe in the console. but -1 does a sorting instead instead of returning the value "-1". but i guess this is defined in the SORT method itself?

Comment: `-1`, `0`, and `1` help define what order means for the items being sorted. Sort uses that to decide which item goes before which, so you define a function that returns `-1`, `0`, and `1` because internally thats how the sort will know what order items belong in; by calling our `compare` function on each `2` elements sequentially from left to right it places the items according to what the `compare` function returns. This happens under the hood which is why we never see `-1`  returned but instead the new ordering. @Selectful

Comment: well not too sure about `sequentially from left to right` but the idea is the same, there's an underlying sort algorithm involved. Check out it's [implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function compare (value1, value2) {
  return value1 - value2;
}

var values = [0, 6, 8, 5];
values.sort(compare);
console.log(values); // 0,5,6,8
```